# Array exclude null values and return everything thats not null

Tags: java, arrays, null

I have a program that is command line based, in which when they enter a command "echo" it buffer writes the words after echo to a file called "talkfile" (this code is omited).

I have chosen the limit to be 100 words. However the user can randomly write anything up to that. The talkfile.write should write all non-null values in the array. When I run this, I get a null pointer error. How can I fix this?

```
String[] inputSplit =  input.split(" ");
switch (inputSplit[0]) {  
case "echo" :
    for (int i = 0; i < inputSplit.length; i++)
    { 
        if (inputSplit[i] == null)
        talkfile.write(inputSplit[1-100]);
        }

     sysOut(talkfile.read());

break;
}
```

Comment: What is `inputSplit[1-100]` supposed to represent? The `-99`th element of `inputSplit`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suppose you meant to write :

```
for (int i = 1; i < inputSplit.length; i++)
{ 
     if (inputSplit[i] != null)
        talkfile.write(inputSplit[i]);
}
```

Comment: We are getting close, this prints the last value in the array, luckily with no errors! How can I include all of the non-nulled values?

Comment: @user2113228 So the user runs the program like `programname "echo a list of items in a list"`, right? In that case, do you mean it only prints out `list`?

Comment: Yes sir. That is exactly what is happening.

Comment: @user2113228 Have you tried just printing out ALL items in `inputSplit`, to check they're there? *(And that there's no issue either with command-line parsing, or splitting I mean...)*

Comment: No, but thats exactly what I need. Whats the most elegant way to write that? 

 talkfile.write(inputSplit[]);   

would require an expression?

Comment: After `input.split(" ");`, try : `for (int i=0; i<inputSplit.length; i++) { System.out.println(inputSplit[i]); }` and let me know if all items are printed out.

Comment: You're welcome, buddy! Glad to have helped! :-) (If you think this answer was helpful, please mark it as correct (the green "tick" next to the answer, so that the community can benefit from it))

Answer (score -1):

```
if (inputSplit[i] != null)
        talkfile.write(inputSplit[1-100]);
```

you checked with  == null.Change it to != null.

Comment: Fixed that. However I am still getting "Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: -99"

@   talkfile.write(inputSplit[1-00]);

Comment: @user2113228 Look at my comment (above) and my answer.